# Не предлагает варианты команд

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Абсолютный новичок, смотрю уроки.
На белом скрине (с урока) начинается писать Rigidbody2D и уже появляются варианты.
У меня же на темном скрине вообще ничего не появляется, в чем причина? Как исправить?
И также когда наводишь курсором на любую команду, сразу появляется её описание, у меня же ничего не появляется, помогите пожалуйста

[image: Мой код]

[image: Скрин с урока]

Comment: Возможно, в уроке используется какой-то `using` выше, которого у Вас нет.

Comment: `using UnityEngine.PhysicsModule;` в начале рядом с остальными `using` напишите, так же прочитайте [это](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.25.php)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть либо из-за того что у вас нет какого-то `using`. Либо из-за того что вы не установили компонент в `visual studio`, для работы с `Unity`.

Comment: Что значит нет какого-то using?

Comment: Для того чтобы дать правильный ответ, можно было пару минут [погуглить](https://unity.xiaomo.info/ScriptReference/UnityEngine.PhysicsModule.html), как устроены пространства имен в Unity. Давать половину ответа - не очень хорошо. Дополните ответ.

Comment: @aepot я даю ответ по своей воле.

Comment: Здесь никого не заставляют давать ответы, но ваш ответ низкого качества, и я по своей воле предложил вам его улучшить.

Comment: @aepot тем не менее нормальный человек может после моих слов решить проблему :)

Comment: Окей, например вы ищите решение своей проблемы, наткнулись на ответ на SO, а там написано, что "быть может, если ты сделаешь эту штуковину, то у тебя что-нибудь получится, но это не точно". Я считаю, что для StackOverflow это не нормально, я голосую против этого ответа, так как данный пост не является ответом на вопрос, и может быть оформлен в виде комментария.

Comment: Ребят, все сделал, нашёл другую тему по этой ссылке https://clck.ru/QRS3K
Нужно было сделать следующее: 
Средства -> Расширения и обновления... (Tools -> Extentions and Updates..)
В появившемся окне вбить в поисковике Unity.
Установить расширение. (Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Unity). Там плагин какой-то, как я понял

Comment: @Rotmayer это как раз тот компонент, про который я и говорил